# jquery map of "form#FormEmail :input" does not work

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input

I am trying to recover all inputs of a `<form>` with jquery. The form and its content like that:

```
<form action="" name="FormEmail" id="FormEmail"  method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="InputName" id="InputName" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="InputEmail" id="InputEmail" value="">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Sujet :</span>
        <input name="InputSubject" id="InputSubject" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">De :</span>
                <input name="InputFrom" id="InputFrom" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" type="text" value="'.$config['mail_contact'].'">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Répondre à :</span>
                <input name="InputReplyTo" id="InputReplyTo" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" type="text" placeholder="'.$config['mail_contact'].'" value="">
                <span class="input-group-addon pointer" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                    <div class="input-group pad-10" style="width:450px">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Copie cachée :</span>
                        <input name="InputBcc" id="InputBcc" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" type="text" value="'">
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom:-20px;">
    <textarea name="TextBody" id="TextBody"></textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

And the jquery code is:

```
var items = $("form#FormEmail :input").map(function(index, elm) {
   return {name: elm.name, type:elm.type, value: $(elm).val()};
});
alert(items.length);
for (index = 0; index < items.length; ++index) {
  alert(items[index]["type"]);
}
```

`items.lenght` is 170  ! Why ? As type, in the alert, I have some `hidden`, `text`, `textarea`, `button` (like 50 times !).

Why `button` so many times and why `$("form#FormEmail :input")` does not take just input elements ?

Thanks.

```js
var items = $("form#FormEmail :input").map(function(index, elm) {
  return {
    name: elm.name,
    type: elm.type,
    value: $(elm).val()
  };
});
alert(items.length);
for (index = 0; index < items.length; ++index) {
  console.log(items[index]["type"]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" name="FormEmail" id="FormEmail" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="InputName" id="InputName" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="InputEmail" id="InputEmail" value="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Sujet :</span>
      <input name="InputSubject" id="InputSubject" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" type="text" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">De :</span>
          <input name="InputFrom" id="InputFrom" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" type="text" value="'.$config['mail_contact'].'">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Répondre à :</span>
          <input name="InputReplyTo" id="InputReplyTo" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" type="text" placeholder="'.$config['mail_contact'].'" value="">
          <span class="input-group-addon pointer" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
            <div class="input-group pad-10" style="width:450px">
              <span class="input-group-addon">Copie cachée :</span>
              <input name="InputBcc" id="InputBcc" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" type="text" value="'">
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-bottom:-20px;">
    <textarea name="TextBody" id="TextBody"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you're looking for `<input>` elements only then why you're using the [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector? The description clearly says: "_Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements_"

Comment: Using your example code `alert(items.length);` alerts "7" (not 170)

Comment: Ok, I understand why I have 170, because I transform the TextareaBody to a WYSIWYG editor with Summernote. http://summernote.org  That's why...I feel stupid :P